# Retrieve primary key of the row that clicked on it (edit and delete button)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview that shows information from a `SqlDatasource`. Now the gridview shows some information with an edit button and a delete button at the end of the row.

I want to retrieve the primary key of that row from a table in C#, when I click on the edit or the delete button.

For this I overriden two functions:

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
   Response.Write(e.NewEditIndex);
}

protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
   Response.Write(SqlDataSource1.DeleteCommand);
}
```

But I cannot retrieve the primary key value. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridView uses `DataKeyNames` property, which a collection of key fields. You may use `GridView1.DataKeys` property to retrieve `KeyField` value.

```
Response.Write(GridView1.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex].Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the bound data object liek that:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].DataBoundItem
```

You must then cast it to your data type and you can access all properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
e.NewEditIndex
```

Gives you the index of row being edited not the key.
To retrive key,get the value from control of the index row

```
Dim gvRow As GridViewRow = lb.BindingContainer ‘Getting current row to get index
 Dim strKey As String = GridView1.DataKeys[gvRow.RowIndex][0].ToString()
```